# Difference between SELECT EXISTS and EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I had an Query like this

```
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT...))

which did not return anything then i changed it to 

    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT...))

and i got my results, can anyone explain the difference?
```

Here the complete query, the change was on line 40:

```
SELECT 
    user_element_status.user_id, 
    user_element_status.element_id, 
    notifications.id 
FROM 
    notifications 
    INNER JOIN notification_element ON  (notification_element.notification_id=notifications.id) 
    INNER JOIN user_element_status  ON  ( 
                                        user_element_status.element_id=notification_element.element_id 
                                    AND 
                                        case
                                            when notifications.notstatus=0 then notifications.notification_status LIKE CONCAT('%',user_element_status.`status`,'%')
                                            when notifications.notstatus=1 then notifications.notification_status NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',user_element_status.`status`,'%')
                                        End 
                                    AND user_element_status.`status` != 'not_required'
                                    AND 
                                        DATE_ADD(
                                        case 
                                            when notifications.notification_trigger='assigned' then user_element_status.assigned 
                                            when notifications.notification_trigger='first_launch' then user_element_status.firstlaunch 
                                            when notifications.notification_trigger='completed' then user_element_status.completedate 
                                            when notifications.notification_trigger='due' then user_element_status.duedate
                                            when notifications.notification_trigger='credited' then user_element_status.creditcompletedate
                                        End 
                                        , INTERVAL triggerdelay DAY)
                                        - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < 0 
                                    )
    INNER JOIN users ON (users.id=user_element_status.user_id AND users.is_active=1)


WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS  ( 
                    SELECT * FROM alreadysent 
                    WHERE 
                        alreadysent.user_id=user_element_status.user_id AND 
                        alreadysent.element_id=notification_element.element_id AND 
                        alreadysent.notification_id=notification_element.notification_id
                )
    AND 
    (EXISTS (
        SELECT
            user_group.user_id,
            element_group.element_id
        FROM user_group
            user_group
            INNER JOIN users ON (users.id=user_group.user_id)
            LEFT JOIN element_group ON (element_group.group_id=user_group.group_id)
            LEFT JOIN elements ON (elements.group_id=user_group.group_id)
            LEFT JOIN element_localization ON ((element_localization.element_id=element_group.element_id OR element_localization.element_id=elements.id) AND users.country_id=element_localization.country_id)
            LEFT JOIN element_arealocalisation ON (element_arealocalisation.element_id = element_group.element_id OR element_arealocalisation.element_id=elements.id)
            LEFT JOIN area_country ON (element_arealocalisation.area_id = area_country.area_id AND area_country.country_id=users.country_id)
        WHERE 
            users.is_active=1 AND
            user_group.user_id=user_element_status.user_id AND
            (element_group.element_id=user_element_status.element_id OR elements.id=user_element_status.element_id) AND
            (element_localization.country_id IS NOT NULL OR area_country.country_id IS NOT NULL)
        ))
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without real queries and schema details.

Comment: Would be useful to see the exact query - I have tried a quick test & get same results for both

Comment: i've added the query

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html); actual syntax is

```
SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE [NOT]EXISTS (Subquery);
```

Per your edit in post, you are actually doing below which is not what you have shown in first query

```
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS  (  subquery )
    AND 
    EXISTS ( subquery )
```

See @siride comments, only difference I can say is in case of `AND (EXISTS (subquery))` if subquery returns rows then it's evaluated as `AND TRUE` whereas in case of `AND (SELECT EXISTS ( subquery ))` it would evaluate as `AND SELECT TRUE` ... *BUT* in either case the `EXISTS` logic should work fine and your query should return same expected result set but per your post you say that the first version `AND (SELECT EXISTS ( subquery ))` doesn't fetch records ... which I am really skeptic about.

Comment: That's strange cause the first query would surely throw syntax error in other RDBMS like `MSSQL`

Comment: yes, but on mysql it worked, and i'm uncertain if my fix is correct

Comment: @wutzebaer: it probably worked on MySQL because MySQL will convert any scalar result into a boolean if in boolean (conditional) context. MSSQL requires a boolean or related operator to run without error.

Comment: I think you are confused, in your actual query the syntax is correct which is not what you have shown in first query. See edit in answer.

Comment: prior it was: AND  (SELECT EXISTS ( subquery ))

Comment: `SELECT EXISTS (subquery)` returns 1 or 0 based on whether there are any rows returned in the subquery. So that basically means the rest is `AND 1` or `AND 0`, which are equivalent to `AND TRUE` or `AND FALSE`. This is legal in MySQL.

Comment: @wutzebaer, see siride comments, only difference I can say is in case of `AND (EXISTS (subquery))` if subquery returns rows then it's evaluated as `AND TRUE` whereas in case of `AND (SELECT EXISTS ( subquery ))` it would evaluate as `AND SELECT TRUE`

Comment: wutzebaer: can you clarify - in first post you said the first query did not work & second did. Your comment on this answer is that both worked (which is what I expect). EXISTS(subquery) returns true or false and as @siride said SELECT true/false will similarly return true/false.

Comment: @siride, true absolutely but either way I see the exist logic should work fine but OP complaining that first approach `AND (SELECT EXISTS (subquery))` doesn't return rows. So he changed to proper syntax and query returned expected rows which I am bit confused about cause to me both version should fetch the same.